# Match on multiple ORed values but know when one using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have working XSLT that searches for a specific element/attribute combination and (1) renames the element as the search attribute value (2) adds an attribute that contains the original element name and (3) deletes the search attribute.  I have this working for two different search elements with the same attribute name but would like to make it a single OR'ed match

```
  <xsl:template match="Values/Value|MultiValue">
```

Is there a way to "capture" the value of the match in order to avoid having to provide a specific attribute value for the StepClass attribute in the XSLT below?  I tried value-of but that is grabbing the element value.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Change Values/Value value of AttributeID -->
<xsl:template match="Values/Value">
  <xsl:element name="{@AttributeID}">
    <xsl:attribute name="StepClass">Value</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Change MultiValue to value of AttributeID -->
<xsl:template match="MultiValue">
  <xsl:element name="{@AttributeID}">
    <xsl:attribute name="StepClass">MultiValue</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!--empty template suppresses this attribute-->
<xsl:template match="@AttributeID" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to "capture" the value of the match

No (at least not easily), but there is a way to capture the name of the matched element:

```
<xsl:attribute name="StepClass">
    <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  Can't thank you enough!  I guess I need to phrase my questions better....